# Действия с числами в assembler, преобразование третьего числа

Tags: ассемблер

Только начал изучать ассемблер, дали лабораторную,задание такое

> В сегменте данных размещены последовательно числа:-1, 2,+128,129,+32769 в минимально необходимом для них формате. Расширить два первых числа до формата слова и записать следом за исходными числами. НА МЕСТО СТАРШЕГО БАЙТА ТРЕТЬЕГО ЧИСЛА ЗАПИСАТЬ СИМВОЛ '#',НА МЕСТО МЛАДШЕГО ЕГО БАЙТА - СИМВОЛ '1'.

Проблема в том, что я не знаю как обратиться к 3 числу(может у меня это получилось).
Вот мой код, он даже запустился (tasm/tlink/tb).

```
.386
dseg segment use16
a db -1
b db 2
с dw +128
d dd +32769
dseg ends
;ЗАПИСАЛ
eseg segment use16
ea dw ?
eb dd ?
ec dd ?
ed dd ?
eseg ends 
cseg segment use16
assume ds:dseg, cs:cseg
; загрузка регистров-указателй сегментов ds и es
m1:
mov cx, dseg
mov ds, cx
mov cx, cseg
mov es, cx
; расширим первые два числа до формата слова,   запишем в es:ea
movzx ax, ds:a
movzx bx, ds:b
mov es:ea, ax
mov es:eb, bx
; Заменим 3 число максимум на решетку, минимум на 1
lea esi,d
mov [esi], byte ptr '1'
add esi,3
mov [esi], byte ptr '#'
; Завершение исполнения
mov ah, 4ch
int 21h
cseg ends
end m1
```

Comment: Когда вы выполняете операцию `mov eax, '#'`, вы заносите код решётки в младший байт регистра ax обнуляя предыдущее значение. Если вы хотите поместить решётку в старший байт eax, то после перемещения кода решётки, вам нужно циклически сдвинуть биты влево.

Comment: @komdosh Спасибо, только я не знаю как это сделать
 'mov shl,eax, '#''   , так?

Comment: Сначала надо определится с размерами числа. Если написано +32769 - то видимо имеется ввиду число со знаком, которое при такой величине в 2 байта уже не запишется, значит его надо делать DD. Если вы хотите работать с ним, как с eax, то сначала заносим в eax '#' обычным mov, потом сдвигаем его влево на 24 бита т.е. shl eax, 24 после чего в AL заносим '1'. НО я бы понял вопрос так, что вас просят занести на место этих чисел, т.е. в оперативную память, а не в регистр.... Кстати, знаковое +128 в один байт не влезает ...

Comment: @Mike Спасибо большое, я сейчас попробую исправить, и как исправлю. Думаю еще вопросы будут

Comment: Если решите писать в память то предлагаю не извращаться, а по одному байту записать, как просят, т.е. что то типа lea esi,d (или offset d, смотря как ваш ассемблер думает). mov [esi], byte ptr '1'; add esi,3 (увеличиваем адрес на 3 байта); mov [esi], byte ptr '#'

Comment: @Mikle Я посидел, разобрался. Код себе поменял (потому, что мне показалось были ошибки). И теперь tlink не хочет создать .exe 
Пожалуйста можете глянуть, что не так?